# SQL Result Repeated Entries

Tags: mysql, sql, wordpress

I'm facing an issue My query is resulting in the correct output but it's repeating, I have used DISTINCT as well in my SQL query

```
SELECT DISTINCT(posts.ID) 
     , posts.post_title
     , posts.post_date
     , posts.post_excerpt
     , posts.post_name
     , postmeta.meta_key 
  FROM wp_posts as posts 
 INNER 
  JOIN wp_postmeta as postmeta 
    ON posts.ID = postmeta.post_id 
 INNER 
  JOIN wp_term_relationships as tax 
    ON posts.ID = tax.object_id  
 INNER 
  JOIN wp_terms as term 
    ON term.term_id = tax.term_taxonomy_id 
 INNER 
  JOIN wp_term_taxonomy as category 
    ON category.term_taxonomy_id = tax.term_taxonomy_id  
 WHERE posts.post_type = 'post' 
   AND posts.post_status = 'publish' 
   AND  category.taxonomy = 'post_tag'  
   AND term.term_id = 70  
 ORDER 
    BY posts.ID DESC
```

The term 70 is tag id and let say if a tag has 100 posts than it is showing the result as 1st id 100 times and 2nd 100 min and so on.

Thank you for your help in advance

Comment: Note that DISTINCT is not a function. For further help, please see: [Why should I provide an MCRE for what seems to me to be a very simple SQL query?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-a-minimal-reproducible-example-for-a-very-simple-sql-query)

Comment: Provide sample data and desired results so it is clear what you mean by duplicates.